# Why don't ionic liquids evaporate in a vacuum?

Tags: astronomy, evaporation, telescopes

Proposals exist for a rotating liquid mercury telescope on the Moon, using ionic mercury.  Pure mercury has a triple point at 312 K and 0.2 mPa, but the Moon's surface pressure is far lower than this.

"Deposition of metal films on an ionic liquid as a basis for a lunar telescope" (Borra et al., doi:10.1038/nature05909) states

> The underlying ionic liquid does not evaporate in a vacuum

Why not?  Ionic liquids have low vapor pressures; does this prevent evaporation, or just reduce it to a rate acceptable for long-term telescopic applications?

Answer (score 1):

Mercury is *not* an "ionic liquid" and it has a high vapor pressure which means it *will* evaporate in a vacuum with even a small amount of added heat.

Answer (score 1):

The study you cite used 1-ethyl3-methylimidazolium ethylsulphate as an ionic liquid, not mercury. The evaporation rate is low but cannot be zero at nonzero temperatures; the reason is that the entropy increase (and thus the Gibbs free energy decrease) is tremendous for the first few molecules entering the gas phase.

The origin of a low vapor pressure is always strong bonding in the condensed-matter state. The notable aspect of room-temperature ionic liquids is that there's something unfavorable about their solid state (e.g., a molecular shape mismatch) that suppresses the tendency to freeze, which strongly bonded matter otherwise tends to do.